# How do you gracefully exit a go uber fx app

Tags: go, go-uber-fx

How do you stop an uber fx as in shutdown the entire program. There seems to be no other way other than ctrl+c

```
func main() {
    fx.New(
        fx.Invoke(register)
    ).Run
}


func register() {
    time.Sleep(5*time.Seconds)
    // shutdown somehow
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [docs](https://pkg.go.dev/go.uber.org/fx#Shutdowner) are not particularly clear, but there's a `Shutdowner` interface available to any Fx module with a `Shutdown` method that requests graceful application shutdown.

Here's a modified part of [the example package](https://pkg.go.dev/go.uber.org/fx#example-package) that will have it simply shutdown upon receiving a request:

```
func NewHandler(logger *log.Logger, shutdowner fx.Shutdowner) (http.Handler, error) {
    logger.Print("Executing NewHandler.")
    return http.HandlerFunc(func(http.ResponseWriter, *http.Request) {
        logger.Print("Got a request. Requesting shutdown now that I've gotten one request.")
        shutdowner.Shutdown()
    }), nil
}
```

Edit: Here's how you could modify your solution:

```
func register(shutdowner fx.Shutdowner) {
    time.Sleep(5*time.Seconds)
    shutdowner.Shutdown()
}
```

Comment: I've actually tried this, after some digging I found one example of this on a chinese google-translated website -- however I was not able to get it to work still, let me try one more time, but wondering if there is anything more to it... I even stepped inside the shutdowner with breakpoints and it just seemed to skip over most of the shutdown logic... that being said, yes docs need to be updated

Comment: It works fine for me on the sample (with my modification), but your `register` example won't be able to really show the behavior. Because you're only calling `Invoke` there is no lifecycle object created to keep the app running on its own. `Invoke` just runs the passed function one time upon startup. If you call `Shutdown` in there, it signals to the runtime to shutdown but the shutdown happens anyways once the function exits. In the sample, the `NewMux` function adds this lifecycle hook to keep things running.

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap it inside a go routine and use context to gracefully exit.

```golang
 import (
    "context"
    "log"
    " go.uber.org/fx"
)


func main() {
    f := fx.New(fx.Invoke(register))

    go func() {
        f.Run()
    }()

    stopCh := make(chan os.Signal)
    signal.Notify(stopCh, syscall.SIGINT, syscall.SIGTERM)
    <-stopCh

    if err := f.Stop(context.Background()); err != nil {
        log.Printf("error stopping gracefully")
    }
}


func register() {
    time.Sleep(5*time.Seconds)
    // shutdown somehow
}
```

Comment: But what if I’d like to shutdown from within one of the invoked methods within the app?